# Can I get a WCF service to generate SoapExceptions instead of FaultExceptions?

Tags: wcf, soap, asmx

Is there a way to get a WCF service which needs to maintain backward compatibility with asmx clients to serialize exceptions as SoapExceptions rather than FaultException or FaultException?

I have some service clients that cannot be upgraded, but we're standardizing all our services to WCF... We've got the services to mimic the asmx soap/xml format, but I can't figure out how to alter WCF's fault behaviour.

Comment: have you considered using WCF extension, and converting your generic fault exceptions to soap exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

WCF does not generate either `SoapException` or `FaultException`. It generates SOAP faults. The client may translate the faults into `SoapException` or `FaultException`.

If the client is an old-style ASMX client, then it will throw a `SoapException` when it receives a fault. A WCF client will throw a `FaultException` when it receives the fault.

The bottom line is that you shouldn't have to change anything.

Comment: I have client which is handling the SoapException. But i dont want to change the client as everywhere they are handling soapexception and then i need to change it to FaultExceptionh all over. Any alternative so that I just use same code (previously there is web service and then i change it to wcf)

Comment: You will not have to change the client code. Just continue to use "Add Web Reference" just like you did when the service was an ASMX service. Remember, the client and service are independent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this. I am using the nettcp binding hope it will not create any issues since web will want http binding? Also do i need to revert the server code to raise soapexception only

Comment: Also tried to add the web reference but the parameters are added extra to the async  methods. Previously its System.IAsyncResult asyncResult only now added System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, out int CreateABCResult, out bool CreateABCResultSpecified

Comment: You cannot get `SoapException` if you use `nettcp`. You can only get `SoapException` if you use an ASMX client (Add Web Reference), and you can't use an ASMX client if you're using nettcp. ASMX only supports HTTP